# Gerrit changes present in db but not shown in UI

Tags: gerrit

Recently I migrated Gerrit on new machine. As part of migration, I took the mysqldump and restored it on new gerrit machine. I ran the reindex operation after restore but the problem is I am not able to see all the reviews on Gerrit UI even if I see them in database table called `changes`

Comment: The lucene index is not stored in the data base. I am not sure, if you were really successful in running the `reindex` command. Check that.

Comment: Please, post the reindex command you've executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @StephenKing mentioned, there was error in reindexing. The error got fixed when I rsynced managed git repositories from old to new gerrit. Once reindex was successful, all changes appeared on UI